# How to remove arrow icon from spinner without removing bottom line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I need to remove the arrow icon at the right of `dropdown spinner`.

I want to display it just like `edittext` field.

I treid `background="@null"`, but it removes both bottom line and arrow icon.

I just want to remove the arrow icon.

Comment: you need to create custom layout for it

Answer (score 2):

just put `android:background="@null"` inside the spinner

Answer (score 1):

Just try background as transparent.

```
 <Spinner
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

OR

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner" name="SpinnerwithNoArrow">
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/edit_text</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom `ArrayAdapter` and pass your custom layout. For example

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);
String[] items = new String[]{"item1", "item2", "item3"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.my_layout, R.id.my_item_tv, items);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where `R.layout.my_layout` is your custom spinner layout (without an arrow) 
and `R.id.my_item_tv` is your textView in the layout which the text will be set to